# How to do a COUNT(*) with GROUP BY in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions

Let's say that I have a List of objects of the following class.

```
class Contact(
    val name: String
    // ...
)
```

I would like to retrieve a `Map<String, Int>` which maps a name to its number of occurences.

On a SQL-based database I would query:

```
SELECT name, count(*) FROM Contact GROUP BY name;
```

What is the best way to do this in Kotlin with higher order functions?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If contacts is of type `List<Contact>` you can do the following:

```
val numOccurencesMap = contacts.groupingBy { it.name }.eachCount()
```

`numOccurencesMap` will be of type `Map<String, Int>`.